# Domain Redirect to another using CNAME Record

Tags: dns, cname

I have a Domain, lets say `maindom.com`, now I want to have another Domain, lets say `secdom.com` to point to `maindom.com` such that all the URL's leads to `maindom.com`. I want to do this with the help of CNAME records **only**. I can use third-party services also.

Example:
`secdom.com/rand123` Leads to `maindom.com/rand123`
`secdom.com/ano2484/anot` Leads to `maindom.com/ano2484/anot`
`secdom.com/tesecqz?id=45` Leads to `maindom.com/tesecqz?id=45`

I tried adding a CNAME record to `secdom.com` with value `maindom.com`, but just din't work.
Another point to note is that the IP of `maindom.com` host other websites also and not just this one, this can be a problem I guess.

How to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DNS setup you configured basically tells users that the site secdom.com is hosted at maindom.com's IP address. Unless you tell the webserver on maindom to accept requests for secdom (by adding a VirtualHost for example), the maindom webserver isn't going to know how to serve up the content for secdom.

If you know what web server you're running on maindom, you can configure it to accept requests for secdom and forward them on to the maindom. For example, on Apache, you could configure a VirtualHost for secdom on maindom and redirect all traffic to it by using .htaccess redirects.

Comment: I am Using a Shared hosting and I do not have access to the apache files, I just have access to 'www' directory. But still how can I setup a Virtual Server or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: The issue you're going to run into is that the web server for maindom.com has no idea how to handle secdom.com as there's nothing in it's configuration that tells it what to do with that site.                You could either send in a ticket to your shared hosting provider and see if they'd add a config to their web server for the domain, setup URL forwarding for the domain if your registrar supports it, or add hosting service for the secdom.com domain and redirect everything to maindom.com.

Answer (score 2):

As well as adding a `CNAME` for `secdom`, you need to add the hostname to the webserver hosting `maindom` so it knows to respond to requests from `secdom`. Ask your host - they should be able to do this easily.

Comment: This seams to me like 'Parking' a Domain to another. I don't/can't do that. Can you tell me a manual way of doing this.